# python pandas recursive lookup between manager and employee ID's

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like below

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    raw_data = {'Emp_ID':[144,220,155,200],
            'Mgr_ID': [200, 144,200,500], 
       'Type': ['O','I','I','I'],
        'Location' : ['India','UK','UK','US']
    }

    df2 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['Emp_ID','Mgr_ID', 'Type','Location'])

    print(df2)
```

[image]

i want to get manager id and ultimate employee ID which he directly/indirectly reporting...suppose manager id 200 directly reporting 144 and 155 and indirectly reporting employee 220. so i want to have separate 3 records for manager 200 like below output..like this for other all manager id's

Wanted output like below

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finding parents/childs or relations between IDs relate to graph theory, so you are better using [Networkx package](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/index.html). You need to install it through `pip` and import it. Create a graph `g` using networkx `from_pandas_edgelist`. For each manager, there are multiple employees directly under him/her. However, each employee is supposed having only one direct manager. So, we start from `Emp_ID`. Call `nx.ancestors` for each employee using genex (or listcomp if you prefer) and passing it to create dataframe `df3`. Finally, `explode` the series of lists of `Mgr_ID` and join back to `df2` to get final output.

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df2, source='Mgr_ID', target='Emp_ID', create_using=nx.DiGraph)

df3 = pd.DataFrame(([list(nx.ancestors(g, x)), x] for x in df2.Emp_ID), 
                   index=df2.index, columns=['Mgr_ID', 'Emp_ID'])

df_final = df3.explode('Mgr_ID').join(df2[['Type', 'Location']])

Out[23]:
  Mgr_ID  Emp_ID Type Location
0    200     144    O    India
0    500     144    O    India
1    144     220    I       UK
1    500     220    I       UK
1    200     220    I       UK
2    200     155    I       UK
2    500     155    I       UK
3    500     200    I       US
```